# Gradle task to open a url in the default browser

Tags: browser, task, gradle

How do I open a a url in the browser from a gradle task ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
task openUrlInBrowser {
   doLast {
       java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse "http://www.google.com".toURI()
   }
}
```

Comment: so simple, but `java.awt.HeadlessException at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:142)` in Gradle 4.10.3 with `gradlew.bat` :(

Comment: Not working, at least in Java 12 for Mac: "> No such property: browse for class: java.awt.Desktop"

Comment: Hi Benjamin, can i reload the browser tab instead of opening a new one?

Answer (score 8):

I made a function from [Robins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22708365/1020871) to support windows and mac

```
def browse(path) {
    def os = org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current()
    if (os.isWindows()) {
        exec { commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "start $path" }
    } else if (os.isMacOsX()) {
        exec { commandLine 'open', "$path" }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
task browseTest {
    doLast {
        def file = project.file('build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html')
        browse file
        browse "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847296/gradle-task-to-open-a-url-in-the-default-browser"
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting error : `Process 'command 'open'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Comment: @ChadBingham What is the context? Can you run the same command from the terminal? Are you on a mac?

Comment: yes, I am on a mac. To solve it I used `task(type: Exec)`, then this syntax worked great.

Comment: how about linux?

Answer (score 6):

```
task showReport(type:Exec) {
  workingDir './build/reports/tests'

  //on windows:
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'start index.html'
}
```

Then run

```
gradle showReport
```

See the information on [Gradle exec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).